# TFS 2010 Build Controller goes unavailable

Tags: build, team-foundation-server

In the last couple of weeks, I've encountered a problem in our TFS 2010 builds: A TFS Build Controller becomes unavailable for seemingly no reason.

I looked into the Event Viewer of the Controller machine, TFS application machine and the VM Host - **not a clue**.

The log of the controller machine shows the following lines every time before the controller became unavailable:

"... *** TFS Server: request to Update BuildController.

... PENDING+ '[Controller Name]': Restart.

... EXECUTE: Restarting '[Controller Name]' from Building. Delayed. Service should stop after stopping running builds.

...PENDING+ '[Controller Name]': Stop.

...Testing a connection from BuildController to BuildAgent '[Agent Name]'..."

Can anyone explain:

1. What does it mean?
2. What can I do about it?

Thanks a lot!

Omer